# Adding a string to the zsh history

Tags: zsh, command-history

The following function

```
function test_hist() {
    print -s "This is a test"
}
zle -N test_hist
bindkey '^X^T' test_hist
```

adds the string `This is a test` to the zsh-history.

If I call the function explicitly by typing `test_hist`, the string is immediately added to the history, but if I call it through the bindkey by pressing ctrl-x ctrl-t, the string is not added to the history straight away. I need to issue another command before I can see it in the history.

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Didn't know that. Just edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that using `fc -R =(print text)` in place of `print -s text` works consistently in and out of a `zle` widget though, so it could be a work around for you.

Looking at the code of zsh 5.8, I find that [`fc -R` seems to let zle know that a new history entry has been added when it detects zle is active](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/zsh-5.8/tree/Src/hist.c#l2800), while [`print -s` doesn't](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/zsh-5.8/tree/Src/builtin.c#l4877).

This patch (on the current git head as of 2020-05-02T22:20+01:00) seems to fix it:

```
diff --git a/Src/builtin.c b/Src/builtin.c
index 3dab3f9b4..551653508 100644
--- a/Src/builtin.c
+++ b/Src/builtin.c
@@ -4918,6 +4918,8 @@ bin_print(char *name, char **args, Options ops, int func)
        ent->stim = ent->ftim = time(NULL);
        ent->node.flags = 0;
        addhistnode(histtab, ent->node.nam, ent);
+       if (zleactive)
+           zleentry(ZLE_CMD_SET_HIST_LINE, curhist);
        unqueue_signals();
        return 0;
    }
```

Not sure if that's the right fix though. I'll submit it to `zsh-workers@zsh.org` ([done now](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2020/msg00586.html)).